jQuery mousenter firing when mouse is over element on document ready / page load
I use this effect to show a navigation, now when i click the link and the page reloads the mouse is mostly still over the element that triggered the event on mousenenter. Now when the page is loaded again the mousenter is fired again and the subnavigation shows. How can i just fire the event when the mouse really enters it from the outside and not on page load?
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  $( "#main-header .shop-nav-item" )
    .on( "mouseenter", function() {
      $("#shop-navigation").addClass("opened")
  });
});


After page reload, it won't trigger hover event until the cursor is moved. Maybe your menu is opened by default or the class is added by other events.
